# Exibindo quantidade massiva de dados

Tags: c#, desempenho, modelagem

A partir do momento que trabalhamos com uma quantidade de dados muito grande(ex: mais de 3 milhões de registros), e que precisamos exibir esses dados na tela enquanto o usuário utiliza a página, sempre tendo a melhor performance possível.

- A divisão dessa lista de dados em grupos menores e a utilização de threads e handlers para exibir esses grupos menores é válida?
- Quais as melhores práticas para exibição?
- Quais os principais fatores que afetam a performance da exibição e porque?
- O quanto a modelagem desse banco de dados é importante em relação a programação nesse caso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com minha experiência, enumero algumas práticas que ajudam neste sentido. Vou citá-las tentando responder na ordem das suas perguntas:

- **Uso de Paginação:**

  - Com certeza é uma boa prática, principalmente pela questão de redução do tráfego de dados. Considere também a correta criação de índices pelo qual as informações poderão ser paginadas (ou "fatiadas"). Aqui cabe também um pouco de "psicologia", pois é sempre interessante que o usuário encontre sua informação o quanto antes. Tanto isto é melhor para ele, quanto para a aplicação que precisará trabalhar menos. Vide o Google, cujo maior trunfo é evitar que a grande maioria das pesquisas não necessitem navegar à segunda página.
- **Query's enxutas:**

  - Para volumes neste nível, o ideal é buscar e transmitir estritamente da fonte de dados somente as informações que serão apresentadas. Isto *pode não dar* impacto tão grande no lado do servidor, mas certamente - em se tratando de uma aplicação Web - terá impacto no tamanho dos dados trafegados. Se for um servidor com alto volume de conexões concorrentes, estas economias fazem diferentes com o crescimento da escala;
- **Agrupamento de Informações**

  - Ocasionalmente você precisará apresentar um resumo ao usuário destas milhões de linhas de informação, tais como totais, tarefas pendentes, últimos lançamentos, etc. Para estes casos, recomendo criar processos no servidor que periodicamente pré-processarão estes resumos. Um exemplo poderia ser a criação [Materialized (Indexed) Views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) no banco, ou um processo próprio agendado que cria estas tabelas resumidas;
- **Cache**

  - Se boa parte das informações apresentadas se repetem em usos consecutivos (Ex: Página Inicial que sempre apresenta os mesmos itens em promoção), você pode se utilizar de framework's que reduzem consultas repetitivas ao banco de dados. Como exemplo no .NET, cito o [NHibernate, que possui cache para query's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/529016/NHibernate-Second-Level-Caching-Implementation);
- **Estrutura do Banco de Dados**

  - A modelagem de dados certamente é importante, pois conforme ela estiver estruturada poderá aumentar ou reduzir a quantidade de trabalho que o banco de dados tiver que realizar. Porém não só isso, a forma como o banco de dados está montado pode ajudar bastante. Um exemplo de boa prática, nos bancos que suportam este recurso, é separar o local físico (disco) de gravação de tabelas e índices, de forma que ambos possam trabalhar paralelamente sem se afetar. Umas horinhas de consultoria de um DBA podem ajudar bastante nisso;
- **Bancos de Dados distribuídos**

  - Aqui começamos a complicar um pouco, mas dependendo do volume de acessos e quantidade de informações pode ser uma saída interessante. Em bancos de dados [Não-SQL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) isso é um pouco mais fácil, através da criação de "fatias" ([Shards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture))) que podem ser processadas paralelamente em servidores distintos.

Por fim, vale lembrar que manter uma boa performance é um trabalho cíclico. As necessidades (problemas) mudam, e suas soluções também. Veja [este site (em inglês)](http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture) com exemplos sobre técnicas adotadas pela equipe do **Youtube** para manter a escalabilidade de um site que recebe mais de **1 bilhão de visualizações/dia**.

Considerando que se já se parta de boas práticas, o primeiro passo é identificar o maior gargalo, e trabalhar nele. Resolvido, o maior gargalo passa a ser outro.

E assim pra sempre segue nossa jornada... :)

Answer (score 0):

> *A divisão dessa lista de dados em grupos menores e a utilização de threads e handlers para exibir esses grupos menores é válida?*

Sim.

> *Quais as melhores práticas para exibição?*

Você realmente precisa renderizar os 3 milhões? Acredito que não importa o que você faça, a performance não vai ser das melhores justamente por conta da quantidade de elementos. Eu trabalharia com um conjunto menor.

> *Quais os principais fatores que afetam a performance da exibição e porque?*

O que afeta a performance é justamente a quantidade de elementos que o navegador precisa renderizar.

> *O quanto a modelagem desse banco de dados é importante em relação a programação nesse caso?*

O banco influencia apenas para obter estes dados. 3 milhões é uma quantidade relativamente alta, logo vale a pena conferir se existem os devidos índices, se o disco e os dados não estão fragmentados.